# How to go through firewall from java program

Tags: java, firewall, telnet, jsch

Ok so here is my problem.

I am working on my local workstation. I have some machine behind firewall and I need to login to this machine from java code. To do this I would like to use JSch library. If I put this machine ip address to web browser I am redirected to firewall login page, and when I enter my credentials I can login to this machine with ssh with this code:

```
public void authenticate(String ip, String user, String password) {
    JSch jsch=new JSch();
    try {
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, ip, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setUserInfo(new UserInfoImpl(password));
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Yes!!");
        session.disconnect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class UserInfoImpl implements UserInfo{

    private String password;
    public UserInfoImpl(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassphrase() { return null;}
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {return password;}
    @Override
    public boolean promptPassphrase(String arg0) {return true;}
    @Override
    public boolean promptPassword(String arg0) {return true;}
    @Override
    public boolean promptYesNo(String arg0) {return true;}
    @Override
    public void showMessage(String arg0) {}

}
```

But my program should autmaticly login also to the firewall. If I use telnet(port 23) instead of ssh(port 22) from my windows command line there is possibility to login to this firewall from there.

Is it possible to login to this firewall from java code (using JSch or some other java library)?

Comment: You probably can but the approach depends on the protocol of what your program is are trying to connect with. Java has libraries from as low level as Sockets to as high level as Http Client. So what service or process are you connecting to? And what is the authentication protocol that the firewall uses to authenticate you?

Answer (score 2):

Blindly connecting to port 22 will probably not direct you to the firewall's web page, so JSch won't handle that for you. When you connect, you'll raise an exception. Catch this and then you can trigger the firewall-redirect with a normal http call port 80, then grab the redirect, parse the result and send a HTTP POST with the right form data.

If the firewall form and address is always the same, you can just send the POST directly before you try to connect to the SSH.

You can use the standard classes for that, see 
[Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty surprising that once you login to your proxy, your are able to access the port 22 of the remote machine, but anyway...

JSch will not help you, but you can easily simulate what your web browser does in java using an HTTP client which is able to handle the correct proxy authentication mechanism.

Since Java 6, the provided URLConnection can handle NTLM (in addition to SOCKS and HTTP Proxies). I would anyway recommend going with [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) 4.2.x which will provide more options and flexibility to help you debug any issue.